# error when validation xml with xsd spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xsd

I want to validate the generated xml, with the xsd file. But I got the following error message.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/text/UTF16
```

Here's my code:

```
public void validateAgainstXSD(File xml) {
        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdFilepath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

And the error message is in the following line:

```
validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
```

Does anyone know why that happened? And what is the solution for successful validation? I really need your help, thank you.

Finally I found where the error lies. The error is in the following XSD:

```
<xs:simpleType name="nameNType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:assertion test="string-length($value) &lt;= 65"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If I comment on the code snippet above, it has been successfully validated and no error message appears as above.

Another question, what is the format so that I can still use the xsd code snippet? How to change it to UTF-8?

Comment: check your all custom xsd are define while processing the xml file. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp)

Comment: means it's probably wrong in xsd format? @NishitCharania

Comment: looks that xml is having issue, is this possible to share your xsd and xml and stack trace ?

Comment: I have checked that the xml is valid. Have you ever had the same error as above?

Comment: From error that you have mention, I can see program not find custom type of "com/ibm/icu/text/UTF16". That is why I asked to validate your xml and asked to define xsd if needed. Hope this will help !

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, in my xml and xsd the top line is defined as UTF-8, but why do I get an error in UTF-16? And I've searched the entire file the word UTF-16 is not found.

Comment: Please provide more details as I [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626023/error-when-validation-xml-with-xsd-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment128290612_72626023).

Comment: Finally I found the location of the error. I've updated in the question above. It will be very helpful if there is a solution from you. Thank you @NishitCharania

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unable to find the class `com/ibm/icu/text/UTF16` indicates 2 things:

1. You don't have that class on your class-path.
2. The parser is trying to parse thinking that either the xsd or XML are using the `UTF-16` character set.

So this leaves a few solutions

To fix 1 you could, find a jar with the character set class, and include it on your class-path. This may work but it would not be my first choice.

To fix 2 you will need to understand why it is trying to use `uft-16`. If this is not correct, you may be able to specify another set when reading your files.
Additionally you may want to investigate where the class `com/ibm/icu/text/UTF16` is being specified, and possibly specify a different character set class.

Typically I ensure that all files I load are in `utf-8`, specify `utf-8` during read, and have it specified at a system level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm still confused, how do we know the xml or xsd is using UTF-16? Whereas in my xml it is defined as UTF-8, here is an example for xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
and for xsd :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Finally I found the location of the error. I've updated in the question above. It will be very helpful if there is a solution from you. Thank you

Comment: Hi @JessicaCathrine I was surprised to hear that commenting out the lines mentioned solved your problem. Although it sounds like there is a specific 'utf-16' Character in the block, I would try removing the assertion and see if you can isolate it to a smaller block of text, then you can look at the number for each char, I suspect that there is a hidden char in there somewhere

Comment: Alternatively you could pump in into a text tool such as notepad ++, show hidden chars and force and encoding change.